# How to configure Java JPA Entity class for MySQL and Oracle DB

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Table(name = EntityBeanConstants.TRANSFORMATION_TABLE)
@Entity // This tells Hibernate to make a table out of this class
public class TransformationEntity extends FSSubResourceEntity implements SearchableDatabaseEntity, IMyTransformation{
  @Id
  @Column(name = "transformation_id", length = 64, nullable = false)
  private String id;

  @Lob
  @Column(name = "source_code", nullable = false, columnDefinition = getColumnDefinition())
  private String sourceCode;

  @Column(name = EntityBeanConstants.DESCRIPTION, length = 1024)
  private String description;


  public static final String getColumnDefinition(){
    return System.getProperty("ENABLED_DATA_BASE") == "MYSQL" ? "LONGTEXT" : "CLOB";
  }
}
```

Getting Error "Attribute value must be constant" while assigning **columnDefinition = getColumnDefinition()**.

when i don't specify columnDefinition it works but when the configured DB is mysql then it takes the column type as TINYTEXT and i want LONGTEXT?

Comment: simply because annotation field value MUST be a constant, cant be resolved at runtime. maybe the `@javax.persistence.Lob` annotation can solve your problem ?

Comment: `columnDefinition` has to be a compile-time constant, so what you are doing won't work. [This](https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/default-clob-length-in-mysql-hibernate-6/7183) mentions a workaround: delete the `columnDefinition` and specify `@Column(..., length = 16_777_216)` instead. I would try that.